# python parallel assignment of 3 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

My question is from a popular coding test.

Given a chain [defined as follows](https://leetcode-cn.com/leetbook/read/illustration-of-algorithm/9pdjbm/):

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None
```

If we want to revert the chain, for example:

Input:1->2->3->4->5->NULL

Output: 5->4->3->2->1->NULL

It can be solved like [this](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/fan-zhuan-lian-biao-lcof/solution/jian-zhi-offer-24-fan-zhuan-lian-biao-die-dai-di-2/):

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur, pre = head, None
        while cur:
            tmp = cur.next 
            cur.next = pre 
            pre = cur      
            cur = tmp     
        return pre
```

But there is [a more compact way](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/fan-zhuan-lian-biao-lcof/solution/jian-zhi-offer-24-fan-zhuan-lian-biao-die-dai-di-2/), which I can't really follow:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        cur, pre = head, None
        while cur:
            cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next
        return pre
```

Because if I change the parallel assignment line to

```
            pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre
```

It wouldn't work properly anymore.

I am wondering how does the parallel assignment of python works, especially in the case that all 3 variables are dynamic.

Comment: Every thing is evaluated on the right first, it essentially creates a tuple of length three (although as a CPython implementation detail/microoptimization, the compiler actually avoids making the tuple in the case of 2 and maybe 3). Then that tuple' items get assigned from left to right to the target list on the left

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write a parallel assignment

```
x, y, z = a, b, c
```

it's equivalent to

```
temp = (a, b, c)
x = temp[0]
y = temp[1]
z = temp[2]
```

So in the failing version, it's equivalent to

```
temp = (cur, cur.next, pre)
pre = temp[0]
cur = temp[1]
cur.next = temp[2]
```

Compare this to the working version:

```
cur.next = temp[0]
pre = temp[1]
cur = temp[2]
```

The difference is that in your version, you assign to `cur.next` *after* you've stepped `cur` to `cur.next`, so you're actually assigning to the original `cur.next.next`.

Comment: I don't understand what the interpreter is actually doing. Does it iterate over the left side assigning values? What would a more complicated unpacking like a , _ , c , d[a] , a.next = tupple look like?

Comment: Yes, that's all it's doing. It's pretty much exactly as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: `a = tuple[0]; _ = tuple[1]; c = tuple[2]; d[a] = tuple[3]; a.next = tuple[4]`